# data binding combobox in GridView

Tags: wpf, gridview, data-binding, combobox, telerik

I'm using the ComboBox in this example inside a GridView as a CellEditTemplate:

```
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="َArticle Description" Width="100">
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.AccDocumentItem.Description1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="SLStandardDescriptionTitle"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AccDocumentItem.SelectedSL.SLStandardDescriptions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}" 
                              Text="{Binding DataContext.AccDocumentItem.Description1,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownOpened">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SLStandardDescriptionsDropDownOpenedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}" CommandParameter="DLType2"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn >
```

I need to present a grid where one column is a combobox. The user can select one value from the list or enter a new value, the problem is that selected row is repeated in all rows. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Your time much appreciated!

Comment: You are binding the Text property of all RadComboBoxes to the same source property. Each article that you are displaying in the GridView should have its own Description property.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Article Description" Width="100">
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description1}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="SLStandardDescriptionTitle"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AccDocumentItem.SelectedSL.SLStandardDescriptions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}" 
                              Text="{Binding Description1,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```